# How does this specific version of A-star algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory, a-star

I was having a course in AI when I came across this problem in A* algorithm:
[image: A_star problem image]

The heuristics are as follows:

```
          N : h(N)
```

---

```
         'A': 9,
         'B': 10,
         'C': 13,
         'D': 9,
         'E': 17,
         'F': 4,
         'G': 0,
         'H': 9,
         'I': 11,
         'J': 2,
         'K': 5,
         'L': 14,
         'M': 4,
         'N': 6,
         'O': 11,
         'P': 4,
         'Q': 4,
         'R': 6,
         'S': 12
```

The start node is 'S' and goal node is 'G'. The internode costs are specified in the image in red. The official answer is the path 'SCDFJG' with cost = 26. The order of node inspection is given as : S,I,C,D,F,H,K,J.

As per my understanding, at each step we choose and expand a node according to the value of the heuristic  f = g + h, where g is the cost of movement from node 'S' to the given node along the path to reach there. For the cases of equal g value, the tie breaker is supposed to be alphabetical order of nodes in the original problem.

#### FAILED Attempts

```
S -> {C,H,I,K}
argmin(f{SC,SH,SI,SK}) = SI
I -> {N,O,L,E}
argmin(f{SIN,SIO,SIL,SIE}) = SIN
.
.
.
path = SINRQG
cost = 36
```

Following the above procedure, I tried for weighted A* (weight W = 3) in which f = g + 3*h, and I got:

```
path = SKHFJG
cost = 48
```

In this case the official answer is the path SINRQG! Now, in the original problem (w = 1), when I apply Dijkstra's algorithm with f as the deciding heuristic in place of g only, the cost is 26 and the order of inspection is S,I,N,K,H,C,D,F,J,G.
So, how do I use A* manually? After some work I could get the code version of the solution from the course:

```
from collections import deque

class Graph:
    

    def __init__(self, adjacency_list):
        self.adjacency_list = adjacency_list

    def get_neighbors(self, v):
        return self.adjacency_list[v]

    # heuristic function with equal values for all nodes, H[n]
.....
def a_star_algorithm(self, start_node, stop_node):
        open_list = set([start_node])
        closed_list = set([])
        g = {}
        g[start_node] = 0
        parents = {}
        parents[start_node] = start_node
        W = 3 #weight

        while len(open_list) > 0:
            n = None

            # Printing open and closed lists
            print(f"Open List: {open_list}")
            print(f"Closed List: {closed_list}")

            for v in open_list:
                if n is None or (g[v] + W*self.h(v)[0], v) < (g[n] + W*self.h(n)[0], n):
                    n = v;

            if n is None:
                print('Path does not exist!')
                return None

            if n == stop_node:
                reconst_path = []
                while parents[n] != n:
                    reconst_path.append(n)
                    n = parents[n]
                reconst_path.append(start_node)
                reconst_path.reverse()
                print('Path found:', reconst_path)
                return reconst_path

            for (m, weight) in self.get_neighbors(n):
                if m not in open_list and m not in closed_list:
                    open_list.add(m)
                    parents[m] = n
                    g[m] = g[n] + weight
                    print(f"Inspecting node {m}")
                    print(g[m]+W*self.h(m)[0])

                else:
                    if g[m] > g[n] + weight:
                        g[m] = g[n] + weight
                        parents[m] = n
                        if m in closed_list:
                            closed_list.remove(m)
                            open_list.add(m)

            open_list.remove(n)
            closed_list.add(n)

        print('Path does not exist!')
        return None

# Test your modified A* algorithm
adjacency_list = {
.......
```

However, I find this too clumsy to understand and implement by hand, though it gives the correct answer.

Comment: You need to consider the estimated cost for the **entire** frontier, not just the nodes adjacent to the last one you picked. In the second step of your failed attempt, you should find `argmin(f{SC,SH,SK,SIN,SIO,SIL,SIE}) = SC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A* star algorithm never discards paths it has expanded. Any of those paths -- short or long -- will still compete with newer paths by their f-values.

You have apparently not done this in your written analysis:

> ```
> S -> {C,H,I,K}
> argmin(f{SC,SH,SI,SK}) = SI
> I -> {N,O,L,E}
> argmin(f{SIN,SIO,SIL,SIE}) = SIN
> .
> .
> .
> path = SINRQG
> cost = 36
> ```

Yes, S expands to C,H,I,K, with these values for g, h and f:

| node | g | h | f=g+h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SI | 6 | 11 | 17 |
| SC | 6 | 13 | 19 |
| SK | 16 | 5 | 21 |
| SH | 16 | 9 | 25 |

And you are right that now node I expands to SIN,SIO,SIL,SIE, but you shouldn't discard SC,SK and SH: they still stay in the "competition"! So we get this:

| node | g | h | f=g+h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SC | 6 | 13 | 19 |
| SK | 16 | 5 | 21 |
| SIN | 16 | 6 | 22 |
| SH | 16 | 9 | 25 |
| SIO | 30 | 11 | 41 |
| SIL | 30 | 14 | 44 |
| SIE | 30 | 17 | 47 |

The next node to expand is thus not N (via SIN), but C (via SC), which is in line with the expected *node inspection order* (S,I,C,...).

If you continue like this, never discarding paths, except the one that is replaced by its extensions, then you'll get the expected results.